# Share variables between classes and activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to write my first android app.

I want to implement swiping, so I added some code for that.

Part of that code is in the `OnCreate` method and part is in it's own class.
In both I need to reference the viewflippers id.

After some reading I created a class that extends the application class.
I have put my variables in it.

In the activity class I can reference it with:

> GlobalVars vars = ((GlobalVars) getApplicationContext());

I can then reference my viewflipper with:

> ViewFlipper viewFlipper = vars.viewFlipper;

Now I want to do the same with the Gesture class for the swiping, but it errors on:

> GlobalVars vars = ((GlobalVars) getApplicationContext());

It says: "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MyGestureDetector"

So how can I reference to these global variables in another class that is not the activity?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://wwwsscce.com) to illustrate what you are trying to do. In particular, it needs to be self-contained so that anyone interested in helping you can copy and paste your code to compile and run it for themselves.

Comment: Probably not the ideal solution, but how about making the variables static? Then you could access it with `*YourClassName*.*variableName*`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your GlobalVars application object with an object that is not an Activity (and therefore doesn't have getApplicationContext()), you will have to provide it to MyGestureDetector detector via constructor or setter.